# Create dynamic pivot sheets with defined sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to create three sheets, rename the sheets with a particular name, and delete or replace them when I run the code again.

The below code is the modified in such a way that it creates two pivot sheet and one sheet with data that creates the count of range defined... with countifs.

I searched the internet for an alternative. I tried the other code but the range(dynamic) is not getting selected while creating pivot table. It throws an error.

```vb
SetwsPT=wb.Worksheets.Add
```

```vb
Sub MacroPivotReceivedResolved()

    Sheets.Add
    pivotWS = ActiveSheet.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "ReceivedMacro!R6C1:R20000C54", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=pivotWS & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable5" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets(pivotWS).Select
    Cells(3, 3).Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Receipt Date")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable5").PivotFields("Receipt Date"), "Count of Case Age", xlCount
    Sheets("ResolvedMacro").Select
    Range("A6").Select
    Sheets.Add
    pivotWS1 = ActiveSheet.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "ResolvedMacro!R6C1:R20000C54", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=pivotWS1 & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable6" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets(pivotWS1).Select
    Cells(3, 3).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Resolved Date")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable6").PivotFields("Resolved Date"), "Count of Case Age", xlCount
    Sheets("ReceivedMacroAge").Select
    Range("A6").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 16.29
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 17.57
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT"
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Outstanding"
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[1]C:R[5]C)"
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Over 8 Weeks (Over 56 Days)"
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(R[9]C:R[1000]C, "">=57"")"
    Range("H3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6-8 Weeks (42-56 days)"
    Range("I3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(INT(R[9]C:R[1000]C>=42), INT(R[9]C:R[1000]C<57))"
    Range("H4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4-6 weeks (28 - 41)"
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(INT(R[9]C:R[1000]C>=28), INT(R[9]C:R[1000]C<42))"
    Range("H5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2-4 Weeks (14 - 27)"
    Range("I5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(INT(R[9]C:R[1000]C>=14), INT(R[9]C:R[1000]C<28))"
    Range("H6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0-2 Weeks (0-13)"
    Range("I6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(INT(R[9]C:R[1000]C>=1), INT(R[9]C:R[1000]C<14))"
    Range("H7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Cases to breach next day ( Day 56)"
    Range("I7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(R[9]C:R[1000]C, ""=56"")"
    Range("H8").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of how to remove and replace a worksheet:

```vb
Sub MacroPivotReceivedResolved()
    Const PIVOTA_NAME As String = "Pivot A"
    
    Dim wsPivot As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'for example
    
    DeleteSheet wb, PIVOTA_NAME 'delete the sheet if it exists
    
    Set wsPivot = wb.Sheets.Add 'add new sheet for pivot table
    wsPivot.Name = PIVOTA_NAME
    
    'create the pivot cache
    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                      SourceData:="ReceivedMacro!R6C1:R20000C54", _
                      Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
    
    'create the pivot table
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=pivotWS.Range("A3"), _
                                 TableName:="PivotTable5", _
                                 DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
    
    'now you can use `pt` instead of `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5")`
    pt.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    With pt.PivotFields("Receipt Date")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Receipt Date"), "Count of Case Age", xlCount
    
End Sub

'Remove any worksheet named `wsName` from workbook `wb`,
'  ignoring any error if no sheet with that name is found
Sub DeleteSheet(wb As Workbook, wsName As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, da As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next                   'ignore error if sheet doesn't exist
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0                        'stop ignoring errors
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        da = Application.DisplayAlerts    'get current setting
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'turn off alerts
        wb.Worksheets(wsName).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = da    'restore previous setting
    End If
End Sub
```